# Flutter how to change string alphabet by index

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a string

```
String word = "000000";
```

What i need to do is change the 0 by index like

`word.replaceAt(1, 3)`  so it will be `300000`

I have search but all are just with replaceWith i want to replace by index

Comment: `String word = "000000";
final replaced = word.replaceRange(0, 1, '3');
print('$word -> $replaced');`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
extension Replacer on String{
  String replaceAt(int index, String replacement){
    return "${this.substring(0, index)}$replacement${this.substring(index + replacement.length)}";
  }
}
```

And use it like:

```
main() {
  String word = "000000";
  word = word.replaceAt(0, "3");
  print(word); // 300000
}
```